# MySQL IN clause special query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a weird thing to do and this would probably imply a weird query. Basically what I have until now is:

```
SELECT * FROM locations WHERE name IN ('city1','city2','country1','city3');
```

This works fine, but I want to alter this query. Say I want to somehow group `city1` with `country1`, so if one of them returns a row (is a valid selector for the query), then the other one shouldn't execute anymore. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM locations WHERE name IN (('city1' OR 'country1'),'city2','city3');
```

This query works, but only returns the values that contain `city2` and `city3`, so not what I want.

Would something like this be possible?

EDIT:
To be more specific, here is an example.

I have 3 locations, which (in PHP), I'm going to break into 5:

`Bucharest, Romania`
`New York`
`Barcelona, Spain`

these will become 3 sets of arrays:

```
array( 'Bucharest', 'Romania' )
array( 'New York' )
array( 'Barcelona', 'Spain' )
```

I want to lookup the continent of each of these locations. I will search for all of them in the same query using `IN` clause from MySQL. I want the query to return 3 rows: `Europe`,`North America`,`Europe`.

However, my query can't find the entry for `Bucharest`, because it's not in the table, so I would want to search for the next term in the array: `Romania`.

Hope this clears things up.

Comment: This does not seem to make sense to me.
The result is a boolean, what should be the difference of the two?

Comment: Might help if you include a bit of sample data. Not entirely sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: `'1','2','3','4'` is `OR`, like `where name like '1' or name like '2' or name like '3' or name like '4'`. What do you want to achieve precisely?

Comment: Do you mean you want to match only either `city1` or `country1` but not both?

Comment: I updated my question with an example, hope it clears things up.

Comment: what if the array would be like this? array( 'Philippines', 'Netherlands' ) what continent would it return?

Comment: @johntotetwoo whichever it finds first. I realize it's not going to be 100% accurate, I just want it as precise as possible, and this is the only thing I could come up with.

Comment: hm, do you want to put all these 5 entries into 1 query and 1 IN clause (`SELECT * FROM locations WHERE name IN ('Bucharest', 'Romania', 'New York', 'Barcelona', 'Spain');` or you want to run query for each array (so 3 queries from that example above) ? it's not fine to put all 5 there and get back 3 matched continents ? even in 1 query for each array, you would get back 1 continent, it's not good ? more i think about it, more puzzled i am :) can't understand what output do you want exactly :)

Comment: @boobiq I want the exact thing that the query in your answer returns (so the answer is good), but if possible without doing many selects (more optimized).

Comment: @EduardLuca aa, i understand now ;) so the only problem is, that one "double - city/country" can return 2 rows, i was still thinking about other case, that one of them returns nothing .. the easiest way would be to just use `DISTINCT` and remove "duplicates", but i think you can't use that

Comment: my query search locations once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is the best solution, but I think you can achieve it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM locations WHERE name IN ('city2','city3')
UNION
(SELECT * FROM locations WHERE name IN ('city1','country1') LIMIT 1)
```

which will select all "non-grouped" names and then select only first row from second select (it will be "city1" if it's matched or "country1" if it's not, or nothing)

But if you want it more general, it has to be done somehow else I think :)

Comment: This works with the mention that there's need for brackets on the second select until after the `LIMIT 1`. Otherwise this is exactly what I want. It's just that I hope there is a better solution than 2 selects (as I have about 2000 values I want to search for). If no better answer shows up, I'll mark this one as the right one. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that your table is too generic - you have two distinct entities (cities and countries) stored in one table.

I would really advise you to alter your database structure to

```
CREATE TABLE countries ( id, name );
CREATE TABLE cities ( id, name, country_id );
```

Then if you want to select cities and their countries use left join

```
SELECT cities.name, countries.name
FROM cities LEFT JOIN countries ON countries.id = cities.country_id
```

If you data looks like:

```
-- countries
id, name
1, Romania
2, Spain

-- cities
id, country_id, name
1,  1,        , Bucharest
2,  2,        , Barcelona
3,  NULL,     , New York
```

the upper query will return exactly what you want

```
Bucharest, Romania
Barcelona, Spain
New York,  NULL
```

Comment: I do have this structure (didn't think it was important). But I also want to add a condition to your query, which messes up the whole result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT inputdata.city, inputdata.country, l.continent_id from
  (
  select 'city1' city, 'country1' country from dual
  union all
  select 'city2' city, null country from dual
  union all 
  select 'city2' city, null country from dual
  ) inputdata
join locations l
on l.name = inputdata.city or l.name = inputdata.country
group by inputdata.city, inputdata.country
```

you should generate the inner query in php...